# OSGi bundle not found despite version match

Tags: osgi, version

My build complains about a missing dependency:

```
... requires bundle org.eclipse.ui [3.106.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
```

The used target platform points to a P2 location that includes the following JAR: `org.eclipse.ui_3.106.0.v20140812-1751.jar`

Still the build fails and raises the following two questions:

1. I thought `3.106.0.v20140812-1751` would be in the range `[3.106.0,4.0.0)`, is that not true?
2. How does OSGi handle the fourth part of a version? If `3.106.0` is a valid version, then how is the suffix `.v20140812-1751` understood by OSGi?

A link to a good explanation of OSGi versioning would also be highly appreciated.

Comment: A good link to versioning : http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Versioning. Note that you should look at the MANIFEST.MF to detect the bundle version rather than in the bundle name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought 3.106.0.v20140812-1751 would be in the range [3.106.0,4.0.0), is that not true?

Yes it is true.

> How does OSGi handle the fourth part of a version? If 3.106.0 is a valid version, then how is the suffix .v20140812-1751 understood by OSGi?

The fourth part is just a segment like any other except that it is sorted alphanumerically rather than purely as a number. The specific algorithm is `String.compare()`, so you should read the standard JavaDocs for that method to get the full details. This segment is called the "qualifier"

In version `3.106.0.v20140812-1751`, the qualifier is `v20140812-1751`. In the version `3.106.0`, the qualifier is the empty string. As the JavaDocs for `String.compare()` will confirm, any non-empty string sorts after the empty string.